# Matching two tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

1. Despatch
2. Activation

`Despatch` table contains data about products dispatched by vendors i.e `DispatchDate`, `LotQty` e.t.c

Activation table contains data of products those are installed in customer's residence which were sent by vendors in `Despatch` table, i.e `ActivationDate`, `LotQty` e.t.c

With the help of below query I have managed to get data with some issue,

```
select
(
    select distinct QTY
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '1007'
)as LotQty

,(
    select COUNT(ProductNumber)
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '1007'
)as ApprovedQty

,(
    select distinct(DispatchDate)
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '1007'
)as DispatchDate

,(
    select distinct(ProductModel)
    from Despatch
    where LOTQty = '1007'
)as Model

,(
    select COUNT(ProductNumber)
    from Activation
    where LotQty = '1007'
)as Installed
```

Which yields the result as below:
[image]

But in above example it takes entire Installed data. My requirement is for every `productNumber` in that particular Lot, it should first check the dispatch date. If Activation date of Installed table is greater than `DispatchDate` of `Despatch` table only then it should consider the entry else ignore it.

**EDITED:**
What I need is roughly something like this

```
(   
 select COUNT(ProductNumber)
 from Activation
 where LotQty = '1007'and ActivationDate in Activation for that ProductNumber >   DispatchDate in Despatch for the same ProductName  
)as Installed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `LotQty` the (only) link between the tables? Can you share the DDL of the tables? What do you actually want to achieve with the query?

Comment: Are DispatchDate and ProductModel unique within LOTQty?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri yes DispatchDate and ProductModel are unique within LotQty. For model A, with lotQty 500 the dispatch date is same for all

Comment: @NickyvV No Product number is present in both too. But I want the data for one particular lot. The result I require is by comparing two tables. For now I need to manually calculate the data. What I need is when I enter particular LotQty I should get all the data referring 2 tables. First 4 column data from Despatch and  for Installed it should compare the productNumber in Despatch with ProductNumber in Activation. If matched it should next check for difference between Dispatch date and Activation date. If Activation date>Dispatch date only then it should be considered as entry

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @NickyvV refer my edit I have provided a rough query structure

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering Activation rows in `OUTER APPLY` expression and the group by Dispath table:

```
DECLARE @D TABLE
    (
      LotQty NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ProductNumber NVARCHAR(50) ,
      DispatchDate DATE ,
      ProductModel NVARCHAR(50)
    )
DECLARE @A TABLE
    (
      LotQty NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ProductNumber NVARCHAR(50) ,
      ActivationDate DATE
    )


INSERT  INTO @d
VALUES  ( '1007', 'N1', '20150112', 'ModelA' ),
        ( '1007', 'N2', '20150112', 'ModelA' ),
        ( '1007', 'N3', '20150112', 'ModelA' ),
        ( '1007', 'N4', '20150112', 'ModelA' ),
        ( '1007', 'N5', '20150112', 'ModelA' )

INSERT  INTO @A
VALUES  ( '1007', 'N1', '20150101' ),
        ( '1007', 'N1', '20150102' ),
        ( '1007', 'N2', '20150101' ),
        ( '1007', 'N2', '20150113' ),
        ( '1007', 'N2', '20150114' ),
        ( '1007', 'N3', '20150205' ),
        ( '1007', 'N4', '20150207' ),
        ( '1007', 'N5', '20150101' )

SELECT  d.LotQty ,
        COUNT(d.ProductNumber) AS ProductNumber ,
        MAX(DispatchDate) AS DispatchDate ,
        MAX(ProductModel) AS ProductModel ,
        SUM(o.c) AS Installed
FROM    @D d
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    COUNT(*) AS c
                      FROM      @A a
                      WHERE     d.LotQty = a.LotQty
                                AND d.ProductNumber = a.ProductNumber
                                AND a.ActivationDate > d.DispatchDate
                      GROUP BY  a.LotQty ,
                                a.ProductNumber
                    ) AS o
WHERE   d.LotQty = '1007'
GROUP BY d.LotQty
```

Output:

```
LotQty  ApprovedQty     DispatchDate    ProductModel    Installed
1007    5               2015-02-15      ModelA          4
```